# How can I use Assert.Throws with property get?

Tags: c#, exception, nunit, assert

I wish to use `Assert.Throws` with a property get.

E.g.

```
object shouldFail = myobj[fakeField];
```

my attempts, albeit bad ones to help demonstrate my need.

```
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => object shouldFail = myobj[fakeField]);
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => myobj[fakeField]);
```

The syntax error I get is
`Only assignment, call, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`. I understand that. So I am asking without a try/catch, how can I test for an exception on that line of code in the e.g. above?

*I am aware of `[ExpectedException(typeof(MyException))]`*

Comment: Side note: property get that throws is somewhat questionable design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do it in lambda with expression since you need to eat return value. Try use statement block instead:

```
Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => { object shouldFail = myobj[fakeField];});
```

Note: it is [not recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to throw from `get`...